# Function is not being called for every session value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am developing a game portal in which professor should be able to add any type of question in it. I have created the question type(multiple choice or descriptive ) functions in form.php and i am including it in my main file. First of all in the loop I am calling main box(simple html box) in which i have to add the question. then i am giving an option to select the question type to add question. On selection of question type, the page loads and submits the form and i am getting that value and saving in dynamically created session variable. Everything is working fine but the main problem is that when i select the question type, it selects that for that specific box but all the other questions disappear. May be its overwriting values in session variable. Please guide me.

```
            <!-- BEGIN BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->

                            <?
            $q_no=5;
            for ($i=0;$i<$q_no; $i++)
            {
            ?>
           <div class="portlet box yellow">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <h4><i class="icon-coffee"></i>#<?echo $i+1;?>     </h4>
                            <div class="tools">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                                <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal"                      class="config"></a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                <form action="newGame.php" method="POST" id="input_type" name="input_type">
               <div class="control-group">
                                   <label class="control-label"  > Add Input</label>
                                   <div class="controls">
                                      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" class="medium m-wrap" tabindex="1" id="type<?echo $i;?>" name="type<?echo $i;?>">
                                      <option value="">Input Type</option>
                                         <option value="1">Multiple Choice</option>
                                         <option value="2">Input Field</option>
                                      </select>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
        </form>

        <?

        //qType();


        $_SESSION["input_type"][$i]= $_POST["type".$i];


        if($_SESSION["input_type"][$i]==1)
        {
        form($q_no);
        }
        elseif($_SESSION["input_type"][$i]==2)
        {

        form1();
        }

        ?>



                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?
                    }

                 ?>
                    <!-- END BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->
```

Here is my form.php file

```
    <?
    function form()
    {

    ?>

    <form  name="1" id="1" action="lecturer.php" method="POST">

    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
    <textarea class="large m-wrap"   placeholder=" Statement " cols="50"rows="3" name="statement<?echo $i;?>"  style="text-align:center;" id="statement<?echo $i;?>"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
    <input name="option<?echo $i.'1';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'1';?>"   placeholder="Option 1" style="width:170px;" type="text"/>

     <input name="option<?echo $i.'2';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'2';?>"    type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 2"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'3';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'3';?>"  type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 3"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'4';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'4';?>" type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 4"/>

     </div>
     <div class="control-group">

     <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'1';?>_default" />
      Option 1
      </label>
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'2';?>_default" checked />
      Option 2
      </label>  
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'3'?>_default" />
      Option 3
      </label> 
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'4';?>_default" />
      Option 4
      </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <p><input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" color="green" class="button" /></p>
      </form>
     <?php
     }
    //end
    ?>

    <?php
    function form1()
    { ?>

    <div class="control-group" id ="field" name="field">
    <label class="control-  label">Answer</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" id ="ans" name="ans" class="m-wrap small" />
                                   </div>
                                </div>
            <?
          }
        ?>
```

The problem is that i have to change the id of everything dynamically because i don't know the exact number of questions and user should be able to add as much questions as he want.

Comment: Can someone solve this problem for me as it is very important for me to solve it. please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `form()` function, you are passing `$q_no`, but there is no parameter when it's declared. First resolve this one, then let me know.

---

### you are only receiving the one output for the current selection, but accessing for the entire loop iteration. This is the one error.

if you want to add multiple choice/input field for individual question, then one of two thing you have to do.

`1)` select option for every question and send form data on any button click rather than option change.

`2)` Use JavaScript trick to solve the issue.

---

I'm going to give you an example here with jQuery. For this you'll have to import jquery in your header

```
<!-- BEGIN BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->



    <?
            $q_no=5;
            for ($i=0;$i<$q_no; $i++)
            {
            ?>
           <div class="portlet box yellow">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <h4><i class="icon-coffee"></i>#<?echo $i+1;?>     </h4>
                            <div class="tools">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                                <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal"                      class="config"></a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                <form action="newGame.php" method="POST" id="input_type" name="input_type">
               <div class="control-group">
                                   <label class="control-label"  > Add Input</label>
                                   <div class="controls">
                                      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" class="medium m-wrap question_type" data-question-no="<?echo $i;?>" tabindex="1" id="type<?echo $i;?>" name="type<?echo $i;?>">
                                      <option value="">Input Type</option>
                                         <option value="1">Multiple Choice</option>
                                         <option value="2">Input Field</option>
                                      </select>
                                   </div>
                                   <div id="answer_no_<?php echo $i ?>"></div>
                                </div>
        </form>

        <?

        //qType();

        ?>



                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

    //jQuery code with ajax in the same file

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.question_type').change(function(){
                var question_no=$(this).attr('data-question-no');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "provide_url",
                    type:'post',
                    data:{
                        type:$(this).val(),
                        i:question_no
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#answer_no_'+question_no).html(data);
                    }

               });
        });
        });
        </script>
                        <?
                        }

                 ?>
                    <!-- END BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->
```

form.php file

```
<?
$i=$_post['i'];
$_SESSION["input_type"][$i]= $_POST["type"];


        if($_SESSION["input_type"][$i]==1)
        {
        form();
        }
        elseif($_SESSION["input_type"][$i]==2)
        {

        form1();
        }


    function form()
    {

    ?>

    <form  name="1" id="1" action="lecturer.php" method="POST">

    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
    <textarea class="large m-wrap"   placeholder=" Statement " cols="50"rows="3" name="statement<?echo $i;?>"  style="text-align:center;" id="statement<?echo $i;?>"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
    <input name="option<?echo $i.'1';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'1';?>"   placeholder="Option 1" style="width:170px;" type="text"/>

     <input name="option<?echo $i.'2';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'2';?>"    type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 2"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'3';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'3';?>"  type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 3"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'4';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'4';?>" type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 4"/>

     </div>
     <div class="control-group">

     <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'1';?>_default" />
      Option 1
      </label>
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'2';?>_default" checked />
      Option 2
      </label>  
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'3'?>_default" />
      Option 3
      </label> 
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option1_default" id="option<?echo $i.'4';?>_default" />
      Option 4
      </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <p><input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" color="green" class="button" /></p>
      </form>
     <?php
     }
    //end
    ?>

    <?php
    function form1()
    { ?>

    <div class="control-group" id ="field" name="field">
    <label class="control-  label">Answer</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" id ="ans" name="ans" class="m-wrap small" />
                                   </div>
                                </div>
            <?
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: sorry it was a mistake i have corrected this one. but problem is not solved kindly help me

Comment: when i change any question type it only calls function for the current box which i am changing but previous changes for other boxes disappears I don't know how to solve this problem
@Ahmad Asjad

Comment: Kindly help me i tried my best but i could not resolve this problem

Comment: the user should be able to change question type for every for every question so id of select box should be different for every question box. and on change only that question should be changed and other should remain the same

Comment: can you answer this question? i need your help again bro
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947911/dynamic-html-form-values-are-not-being-stored-in-database?noredirect=1#comment55655129_33947911
@Ahmad Asjad

Comment: here id's are not changing dynamically. can you please help me