# Dynamic html form values are not being stored in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am developing a game portal in which professor should be able to add any type of questions in a game. I have created the question type(multiple choice or descriptive ) functions in form.php and i am calling them in my main file. First of all in the loop I am calling main box(simple html box) in which i have to add the question. And its working fine. Now i have to store the dynamically changed boxes values in database. But i don't know where i am wrong. Following is my form.php in which i am creating forms to call in the main file.

```
    <?
    $i=$_post['i'];
    $_SESSION["input_type"][$i]= $_POST["type"];
    if($_SESSION["input_type"][$i]==1)
    {
    form($i);
    }
    elseif($_SESSION["input_type"][$i]==2)
    {
    form1();
    }

    function form($i)
    {

    ?>

    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <textarea class="large m-wrap"   placeholder=" Statement " cols="50"rows="3" name="statement<?echo $i;?>"  style="text-align:center;" id="statement<?echo $i;?>"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
    <input name="option<?echo $i.'1';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'1';?>"   placeholder="Option 1" style="width:170px;" type="text"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'2';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'2';?>"    type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 2"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'3';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'3';?>"  type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 3"/>

    <input name="option<?echo $i.'4';?>" id="option<?echo $i.'4';?>" type="text" style="width:170px;" placeholder="Option 4"/>

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="option<?echo $i.'1';?>_default" id="option<?echo $i.'1';?>_default" />
    Option 1
    </label>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="option<?echo $i.'2';?>_default" id="option<?echo $i.'2';?>_default" checked />
    Option 2
    </label>  
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="option<?echo $i.'3';?>_default" id="option<?echo $i.'3'?>_default" />
    Option 3
    </label> 
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="option<?echo $i.'4';?>_default" id="option<?echo $i.'4';?>_default" />
    Option 4
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
    //end
    ?>

   <?php
   function form1()
   { ?>

   <div class="control-group" id ="field" name="field">
   <label class="control-  label">Answer</label>
   <div class="controls">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" id ="ans" name="ans" class="m-wrap small" />
                               </div>
                            </div>
        <?
      }
    ?>
```

This is my main file in which i am cakking the form.php functions to add questions

```
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE -->
     <div class="page-content">
     <form action="storeGame.php" method="POST">
     <div class="control-group">

      <label class="control-label">Game Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="game_name" name="game_name" placeholder="Enter Game Name" class="m-wrap large" />
      </div>
      </div>        

     <!-- BEGIN BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->

     <?
        $q_no=5;
        for ($i=0;$i<$_SESSION["q_inc"]; $i++)
        {
        ?>
       <div class="portlet box yellow">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <h4><i class="icon-coffee"></i>#<?echo $i+1;?>         </h4>
                        <div class="tools">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                            <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal"                      class="config"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
            <form action="newGame.php" method="POST" id="input_type" name="input_type">
           <div class="control-group">
                               <label class="control-label"  > Add Input</label>
                               <div class="controls">
                                  <select  class="medium m-wrap question_type" data-question-no="<?echo $i;?>" tabindex="1" id="type<?echo $i;?>" name="type<?echo $i;?>">
                                  <option value="">Input Type</option>
                                     <option value="1">Multiple Choice</option>
                                     <option value="2">Input Field</option>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                               <div id="answer_no_<?php echo $i ?>"></div>
                            </div>
    </form>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.question_type').change(function(){
            var question_no=$(this).attr('data-question-no');
            $.ajax({
                url: "form.php",
                type:'post',
                data:{
                    type:$(this).val(),
                    i:question_no
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#answer_no_'+question_no).html(data);
                }

           });
    });
    });
    </script>
                    <?
                    }

             ?>

                    <!-- END BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->

        <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <!-- BEGIN STYLE CUSTOMIZER -->
                    <div class="color-panel hidden-phone">
                        <div class="color-mode-icons icon-color"></div>
                        <div class="color-mode-icons icon-color-close"></div>
                        <div class="color-mode">
                            <p>THEME COLOR</p>
                            <ul class="inline">
                                <li class="color-black current color-default" data-style="default"></li>
                                <li class="color-blue" data-style="blue"></li>
                                <li class="color-brown" data-style="brown"></li>
                                <li class="color-purple" data-style="purple"></li>
                                <li class="color-white color-light" data-style="light"></li>
                            </ul>
                            <label class="hidden-phone">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="header" checked value="" />
                            <span class="color-mode-label">Fixed Header</span>
                            </label>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END BEGIN STYLE CUSTOMIZER --> 
                    <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->           
                    <h3 class="page-title">

                    </h3>

                    <!-- END PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12" >

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST" >
                <input type="hidden" id="session" data="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session['questNo']" />
            <!--    <a  class="btn green"  type="submit" ><i class="icon-plus" ></i></a> -->
            <button type="submit" id="add_q" name="add_q" class="btn green"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                                    </form>

            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER-->  
        <button type="submit" class="btn yellow btn-block" id="getGames" name="getGames" class="btn green">Create Game    <i &nbsp class="m-icon-big-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>                  
                </form>
                </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE -->
```

And below is my storeGame.php file in which i am getting values of question fields and saving in the database but the dynamic box values are not being saved but all other box values are being saved.

```
    <?
    session_start();
    include_once("../Includes/db_connection.php");
    $lecturer_id = $_SESSION["lecturer_id"];
    $game_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['game_name']);
    echo $_SESSION["lecturer_id"];;
    echo $game_name;
    mysql_query("insert into games(game_name, lecturer_id) values ('$game_name', '$lecturer_id')");
    for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION["q_inc"];$i++)
    {
      $input_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'.$i]);
      if($input_type=='1') 
      {
      $question= $_POST['statement'.$i];
      $val1= $_POST['option'.$i.'1'];
      $val2= $_POST['option'.$i.'2'];
      $val3= $_POST['option'.$i.'3'];
      $val4= $_POST['option'.$i.'4'];
      $default1= $_POST['option'.$i.'1'.'_default'];
      $default2= $_POST['option'.$i.'2'.'_default'];
      $default3= $_POST['option'.$i.'3'.'_default'];
      $default4= $_POST['option'.$i.'4'.'_default'];
      mysql_query("insert into subgames(game_id, input_id, statement, option1, option2, option3, option4, default1, default2, default3, default4) values ((SELECT id 
     FROM games WHERE game_name = '$game_name'), '$input_type', '$question', '$val1', '$val2', '$val3', '$val4', '$default1', '$default2', '$default3', '$default4')");
     $error= mysql_error();
     }
     elseif($input_type=='2')
     {
     $question= $_POST['quest'];
     $answer= $_POST['ans'];
     // it is not implemented so leave it
     }

     }
```

Kindly help me i have tried a lot but i don't know where i am wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: `function form()` has var `$i` and i don't see you define this var in function

Comment: @Standej, this function is being called in main file in loop where is is changing in loop. do i need to define it in this file also? kindly guide me

Comment: If you want to use var `$i` into function you need to call a function like `form($i);` and when you writing function do `function form($i){ // your function }` In this you can use $i var in function

Comment: @Standej, sorry that's my mistake. I have updated the code but still the values are not being stored in database.

Comment: Okay good. Next I don't see in your `form($i)` function `<form>` tag I also don't see where do you submitting this input fields and which method you use POST or GET.

Comment: @Standej, if you see in the main file, there is form on the top in which i am calling this function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96301/discussion-between-muhammad-umar-and-standej).

Comment: Someone please guide me. I have tried a lot but i don't know why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to tell you that there are lots of problem in your code. Those I got are as follows.

**1:** There is no need to paste the entire html code of header and footer as well. This causes to skipped from the people who can give you answer, they run away after seeing lots of code. i.e. unnecessary.

**2:** You have defined multiple form tags, and these forms are nested to each other. every form should be closed before opening any other form tag.

**3:** Radio button tag's name should have the same for every group of the option, their value should be different not the name. for example for gender there should be two radio input tag with same name name="gender" and with different value like value="male" & value="female". you'll get the only one value for the radio button with same name.

**4:** if you are going to use session anywhere on the page, it first of all should be started before printing any output.

**5:** You have not given any value for the default value of radio button. So there should be a value attribute with different value inside that

**6:** whenever you are going to name a funtion, name it according to its functionality, not like a, b, c. Here I'm going to change your form to form_multiple() and form1 to form_input()

**7:** when you are going to choose input field for more than one question, then you'll have two input field with the same name, that is not allowed. So, let here also pass the i to the function.

====================

**here is the solution for your code.**

**1:**  I have removed the numbers from default in radio button.

---

### **form.php**

```
<?php
$i = $_POST['i'];
$_SESSION["input_type"][$i] = $_POST["type"];
if ($_SESSION["input_type"][$i] == 1) {
    form_multiple($i);
} elseif ($_SESSION["input_type"][$i] == 2) {
    form_input($i);
}

function form_multiple($i)
{
    ?>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="large m-wrap" placeholder=" Statement " cols="50" rows="3" name="statement<?php echo $i; ?>" style="text-align:center;" id="statement<?php echo $i; ?>"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <input name="option<?php echo $i . '1'; ?>" id="option<?php echo $i . '1'; ?>" placeholder="Option 1"
               style="width:170px;" type="text"/>

        <input name="option<?php echo $i . '2'; ?>" id="option<?php echo $i . '2'; ?>" type="text" style="width:170px;"
               placeholder="Option 2"/>

        <input name="option<?php echo $i . '3'; ?>" id="option<?php echo $i . '3'; ?>" type="text" style="width:170px;"
               placeholder="Option 3"/>

        <input name="option<?php echo $i . '4'; ?>" id="option<?php echo $i . '4'; ?>" type="text" style="width:170px;"
               placeholder="Option 4"/>

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            Choose Default Option
            <br/>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="option<?php echo $i; ?>_default" id="option<?php echo $i . '1'; ?>_default"/>
                Option 1
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" value="2" name="option<?php echo $i; ?>_default" id="option<?php echo $i . '2'; ?>_default"
                       checked />
                Option 2
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" value="3" name="option<?php echo $i; ?>_default" id="option<?php echo $i . '3' ?>_default"/>
                Option 3
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" value="4" name="option<?php echo $i; ?>_default" id="option<?php echo $i . '4'; ?>_default"/>
                Option 4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
//end
?>

<?php
function form_input($i)
{
    ?>
    <div class="control-group" id="field" name="field">
        <label class="control-  label">Answer</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" id="ans" name="ans_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="m-wrap small"/>
        </div>
    </div><?php
}
?>
```

=====================================

In the below page I have removed some of the tags to shorten the answer
and I also have commented the form tags, so that you can analyze your errors. These two forms were inside another form tag
I don't know where you have defined `$_SESSION["q_inc"]` variable. I assume that this variable will have some integer value inside.

---

### **main content page**

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("../Includes/db_connection.php");
//include_once("form.php");
if(isset($_POST['total_q'])){
$_SESSION["q_inc"]=$_POST['total_q'];
}
if (!isset($_SESSION["q_inc"])) {
    $_SESSION["q_inc"] = 2;
}

$_SESSION["questNo"] = $_SESSION["q_inc"];
if (!isset($_SESSION["lecturer_id"])) {
    header("Location:../login.php");
}
//if($_SERVER['add_q'] == 'POST')
//$counter=0;


if (isset($_POST['add_q'])) {
    $_SESSION["q_inc"]++;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery.js"></script>


    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>ClassEx</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="" name="description"/>
    <meta content="" name="author"/>
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/bootstrap-fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/css/style_responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/css/style_default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_color"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/chosen-bootstrap/chosen/chosen.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/uniform/css/uniform.default.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/img/favicon.ico"/>

</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->
<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body class="fixed-top">
<!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
<div class="header navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION BAR -->
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
            <a class="brand" href="#">
                <img src="../assets/img/logoclassex.jpg" alt="logo" height="35px" width="35px""/>
            </a>
            <!-- END LOGO -->
            <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <img src="../assets/img/menu-toggler.png" alt=""/>
            </a>
            <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
            <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
            <ul class="nav pull-right">


                <!-- BEGIN NOTIFICATION DROPDOWN -->

                <!-- END NOTIFICATION DROPDOWN -->
                <!-- BEGIN INBOX DROPDOWN -->

                <!-- END INBOX DROPDOWN -->
                <!-- BEGIN TODO DROPDOWN -->

                <!-- END TODO DROPDOWN -->

            </ul>
            <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION BAR -->
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
<!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container row-fluid">
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
    <div class="page-sidebar nav-collapse collapse">
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
                <div class="sidebar-toggler hidden-phone"></div>
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
            </li>

            <li class="start ">
                <a href="lecturer.php">
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                    <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>


            <li class="">
                <a href="../includes/logout.php">
                    <i class=" icon-off"></i>
                    <span class="title">Logout</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU -->
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE -->
    <div class="page-content">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST" >
            <input type="hidden" id="session" data="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session['questNo']" />
            <!--    <a  class="btn green"  type="submit" ><i class="icon-plus" ></i></a> -->
            Enter no of question<input name="total_q" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" />
            <!--<button type="submit" id="add_q" name="add_q" class="btn green"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>-->
        </form>
        <form action="storeGame.php" method="POST">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Game Name</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="game_name" name="game_name" placeholder="Enter Game Name"
                           class="m-wrap large"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- BEGIN BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->
            <?php
            $q_no = 5;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION["q_inc"]; $i++) {
                $temp = $i;
                ?>
                <div class="portlet box yellow">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <h4><i class="icon-coffee"></i>#<?php echo ($temp + 1); ?></h4>

                        <div class="tools">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                            <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label"> Add Input</label>

                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select class="medium m-wrap question_type" data-question-no="<?php echo $i; ?>"
                                            tabindex="1" id="type<?php echo $i; ?>" name="type<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                        <option value="">Input Type</option>
                                        <option value="1">Multiple Choice</option>
                                        <option value="2">Input Field</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div id="answer_no_<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
                            </div>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.question_type').change(function () {
                        var question_no = $(this).attr('data-question-no');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "form.php",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                type: $(this).val(),
                                i: question_no
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#answer_no_' + question_no).html(data);
                            }

                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <!-- END BORDERED TABLE PORTLET-->

            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER-->
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">

                        <!--                    <form action="-->
                        <?php //echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?><!--"  method="POST" >-->
                        <!--                        <input type="hidden" id="session" data="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session['questNo']" />-->
                        <!--                        <button type="submit" id="add_q" name="add_q" class="btn green"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>-->
                        <!--                    </form>-->

                    </div>
                    <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
                </div>
                <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER-->
                <button type="submit" class="btn yellow btn-block" id="getGames" name="getGames" class="btn green">
                    Create Game <i &nbsp class="m-icon-big-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END PAGE -->
</div>
<!-- END CONTAINER -->
<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
<div class="footer">
    University of Passau ClassEx Team
    <div class="span pull-right">
        <span class="go-top"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END FOOTER -->
<!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
<!-- Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/breakpoints/breakpoints.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/jquery-slimscroll/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.blockui.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/chosen-bootstrap/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ie8 fixes -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../assets/js/excanvas.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // initiate layout and plugins
        App.setPage('calendar');
        App.init();
    });
</script>
<!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

===============================

There should be only one default option field in the database. Here I have removed all those and added one named `"default_option"`

---

### **storeGame.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("../Includes/db_connection.php");
$lecturer_id = $_SESSION["lecturer_id"];
$game_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['game_name']);
echo $_SESSION["lecturer_id"];;
echo $game_name;
$sql="insert into games(game_name, lecturer_id) values ('$game_name', '$lecturer_id')";
if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    echo "Error in storing into database!<br/>";
}

for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION["q_inc"];$i++)
{
    $input_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'.$i]);
    if($input_type=='1')
    {
        $question= $_POST['statement'.$i];
        $val1= $_POST['option'.$i.'1'];
        $val2= $_POST['option'.$i.'2'];
        $val3= $_POST['option'.$i.'3'];
        $val4= $_POST['option'.$i.'4'];
        //Here should be only one default value
        $default_option= $_POST['option'.$i.'_default'];
        /*$default1= $_POST['option'.$i.'1'.'_default'];
        $default2= $_POST['option'.$i.'2'.'_default'];
        $default3= $_POST['option'.$i.'3'.'_default'];
        $default4= $_POST['option'.$i.'4'.'_default'];*/
        $sql="  insert into subgames(   game_id,                                                        input_id,       statement,      option1,    option2, option3, option4, default_option)
                             values (   (SELECT id FROM games WHERE game_name = '$game_name' limit 1),  '$input_type',  '$question',    '$val1',    '$val2', '$val3', '$val4', '$default_option')";
        if(!mysql_query($sql)){
            echo "Error";
        }
        else{
            echo "Success";
        }
        //$error= mysql_error();
    }
    elseif($input_type=='2')
    {
        $question= $_POST['quest'];
        $answer= $_POST['ans'];
        // it is not implemented so leave it
    }

}
```

Comment: I have implemented your code. but the problem is that the id's of boxes are not being changed for every question. and you know the names of default option radio buttons are same so we can chose only one even if the questions are more than one. so due to this we can't select the default option for every question.

Comment: secondly brother i think the id's of statement and 4 answers are also not changing as the system is not getting them and they are not being stored in the database.